# Show $V_a^b(u)=\int_{[a,b]} d\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $u:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}\in BV([a,b])$ be left-continuous and of bounded variation, i.e $$V_a^b(u)=\sup_{a=t_0<\dots<t_l=b} \sum_{i=1}^{l} |u(t_i)-u(t_{i-1})|<\infty$$ for a partition $a=t_0<\dots<t_l=b$ of $[a,b]$.

Let $\lambda$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathcal{B}([a,b])$ and let $\sigma:[a,b]\to \{-1,1\}$ be a $\lambda$-measurable function.

> Show $V_a^b(u)=\int_{[a,b]} d\lambda.$

Any ideas how to do this? A previous exercise shows $u\in BV([a,b])$ satisfies $u(y)-u(x)=\int_{[x,y)} u\sigma d\lambda$ so applying this I get $\sigma^{-1}(b)-\sigma^{-1}(a)=\int_{[a,b)} d\lambda$ but other than that I have no idea.

Comment: Is the statement about $V_a^b(\sigma)$ ? Or is it about $\int_{[a,b]} ud\lambda$ ? Also $\sigma^{-1}$ is defined on $\{-1,1\}$ not $[a,b]$

Comment: The statement about previous question is also non clear, if you change to $-\sigma$, you suppose to get $u(x)-u(y)$ which you don't right now.

Comment: Where does $\sigma$ feature?

Comment: There is no $\sigma$ in the statement, so what I did is probably stupid.

Comment: Can you fix previous exercise's statement as well as the question ? I'm expecting something like $V_a^b(u)=\sup_\sigma \int_{[a,b]}\sigma u d\lambda$ using $\sigma(x)(u(y)-u(x)) = \int_{[x,y)} u\sigma d\lambda$. And maybe can you provide a proof for last exercise too ?